# How to convert utc date in to milliseconds - moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to compare two dates using moments in my ReactJs App.
before compare two days,I have to converts dates into milliseconds.

i tried `valueOf()` but it's not returning milliseconds.how can i get milliseconds for below formated dates?

```
var s_date = moment(this.props.s_date).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");

var e_date = moment(this.props.e_date).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
moment(this.props.s_date).valueOf()
moment(this.props.e_date).valueOf()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s_date = moment(this.props.s_date);

var e_date = moment(this.props.e_date);

var diff = e_date - s_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you used `valueOf` but by looking at the docs this should work:

```
var s_date = moment(this.props.s_date).utc().valueOf()

var e_date = moment(this.props.e_date).utc().valueOf()

pseudo code: e_date > s_date
```

After you compare dates then format like:

```
s_date.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")
```

BTW. you do not have to convert to miliseconds to compare dates. It would be enough to do:

```
if(s_date > e_date) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: but `moment(this.props.s_date)` and `moment(this.props.s_date).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]") `returning two different times. `moment(this.props.s_date).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]") - 2019-06-17T15:00:00.000Z `,` moment(this.props.s_date)` - `Tue Jun 18 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: 1) it doesn't matter at all if you will format to utc after comparision, 2) you do NOT have to convert to miliseconds to compare 3) can you post an example on how you used valueOf(), I tried it a second ago and it worked fine with and without utc()

Comment: I updated the code, in summary, first transform the milliseconds then format.